# Typeerror 1009 in flash csh AS3 in different scenes

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have two action-layers in two Scenes in my flash project.

```
options_button.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testfunction);

function testfunction(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 2");
}

    }
```

and in scene 2's action layer

```
btn_return.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testfunctionn);

function testfunctionn(event:MouseEvent):void

{

gotoAndPlay(1, "Scene 1");

}
```

But when i click the options_button button this message gets thrown:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference
at btnOptions/frame201()[btnOptions::frame201:1]
at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndPlay()
at btnOptions/testfunction()[btnOptions::frame1:5]
```

I have a image from my debug that points an arrow to
`btn_return.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testfunctionn);`

EDIT:
I had approximatly 100 blank keyframes until the instance was "keyframed" removing all these so the instance was at frame one "solved" it. 
Is the moral of the story that buttons should always start at frame one?

Comment: Something is null in frame 201 in btnOptions. What? If that line is `btn_return.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, testfunctionn);` then btn_return is null.

Comment: [The moral of the story](http://www.developria.com/2010/04/combining-the-timeline-with-oo.html) is don't try to listen to an object until the variable that contains it has been populated with an actual object.